# Weird behavior with directives and angular form validation

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a custom directive to help me creating bootstrap forms and dealing with form validation using angular.

I've come up so far with the following directive:

```
directive('formGroup', ['$compile',function ($compile) {
  var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var fieldName = attrs.formGroup;
      var formName = attrs.form;

      if (formName === undefined || formName === null) {
          //find form name
          formName = $(element).closest('form').attr('name');

          if (formName === undefined || formName === null) {
              console.error('Could not find form name for error ' + fieldName);
          }
      }

      var showErrorOn = formName + '.' + fieldName + '.$invalid';

      $(element).addClass('form-group');
      $(element).attr('ng-class', '{ \'has-error\' : ' + showErrorOn + ' }');
      $(element).removeAttr('form-group');
      $compile(element)(scope);
  }

  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: linker
  }}]);
```

To be used with the following HTML:

```
<form name="testForm" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" form-group="email">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="email" required  />
        </div>
    </div>    
</form>
```

The point of the directive is a couple of things:

1. Finding the form name so I don't have to type it again for every field.
2. Add the class "form-group".
3. Add the class "has-error" whenever the field is invalid.

Everything seems to work just fine until I type a valid e-mail address and add a dot to the end (making the input invalid). After I do that, the input automatically clears out but I can't understand why.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgwocdyu/2/

To reproduce type: "a@email" then type "." and the input will go blank.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel laying a bunch of jQuery over top of angular for this. Angular built in form validation is powerful and more advanced than what you are doing

Comment: @charlietfl I think you didn't understand how the directive works. I am using Angular built in form validation but trying to avoid writing a lot of repetitive code.